# How can I make a responsive layout with bootstrap that goes from 3 to 2 to 1 columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a three column layout done with Bootstrap 3. It works great in full size, with three columns, and with one column for small screens. In between, with two columns, it doesn't fill in all the space and looks like

```
* *
*
* *
*
* *
*
```

How can I make it fill in all the space in the medium size layout?

My current classes for the items are `col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6`

Full example code can be viewed here: http://majca.org/bootstrap_thumb_test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to remove `<div class='row'>` from every **3n count** div because that is troubling your layout.

This way, since you have `col-md-4` for divs and BS follows `12 grid system`,you'll have max 3 divs in max-resolution and on resize it wont break the alignment

Check fiddle  [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/xb5a4/1/) 
 (*i have removed only one row class to demonstrate*)

Comment: Your fiddle is not working for me, I think you missed to remove one closing `</div>` Here is the [updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/xb5a4/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Put everything in one row.  You have two rows right now in your mark-up and Bootstrap will always line break after the 3rd (and last) element in each row.

So instead of

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

Use this

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```